# Skipping the first list of a list

Tags: python

I have imported an excel file.

I have stripped out the white space and split the data to make a list of list.

```
for i in range(len(Data)):
  Data[i] = sData[i].strip().split(',')
```

Now I want to convert the 2nd element in every list to an integer.

Except the first line of code Data[0] are the titles from excel.

Which obviously cannot be converted to an int.

How do I skip over the first list Data[0] to convert the 2nd element Data[1][1] in the following lists?

I thought it would be something like this:

```
Data[i][0:] = int(Data[i][1])
```

But I am wrong. Any advice?

Comment: Could you please add an example of your data structure. It makes it easier to give you a solution.

Comment: `for row in Data[1:]:`? Or to support your current loop just set `Data[0]` outside the loop and then loop on `for i in range(1, range(len(Data)))`

Answer (score 1):

Process the rows after the first?

```
for row in Data[1:]:
  row[1] = int(row[1])
```

Or do it in your existing loop:

```
  if i:
    Data[i][1] = int(Data[i][1])
```